# Splitting fields of $F$-algebra $F[X]/(P(X))$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, splitting-field

> Let $F$ be a field and $P(X)\in F[X]$ a polynomial of degree $d\ge 1$.
>   Describe the splitting fields of $F$-algebra $A=F[X]/(P(X))$.

**My try:** For every $a\in A$, there exists $f(X), g(X)\in F[X]$, $\deg g(X)<d$, such that
$$ a = f(X)+(P(X)) = g(X)+(P(X)).$$
Could you please tell me how to connect an element in $A\otimes_F K$ with a matrix in $M_n(K)$? Thanks.

Comment: $A\otimes_F K =K[X]/(P(X)) $ is a finite dimensional $K$-vector space with basis $X^j,j\le d-1$, then for $a\in A$, $aX^j = \sum_{i\le d-1} T(a)_{i,j}X^i$ where $T(a)\in  M_n(F)$. Taking $K$ the splitting field of $P(X)$ then every $T(a)$ has a Jordan normal form $\in M_n(K)$ given by the isomorphism $K[X]/(P(X))\to \prod_l K[Y]/(Y-\beta_l)^{e_l})\to \prod_l K[Z]/(Z^{e_l})$, they are all diagonalizable iff $P(X)$ has no double root in which case $A\otimes_F K\cong K^d$

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!